# Aggregate latest events from social networking website

Tags: jakarta-ee

I want to get the latest events from he any website. And want to show them on my jsp page. Here events are any latest things which are released like books, movies etc. Which framework will be used for that. I read google open social api but did not get any help. I want to use java.